# Highcharts: getting runtime durations on the yAxis

Tags: time, highcharts, time-series

I run daily a job. Today, that job takes 1:45:09 hrs. I have a lot of such durations for that job from the past weeks and I want to be able to show that graphically using a simple column chart. On the Y axis I want duration ticks from 0:00:00 - 5:00:00 or so that I can easily compare the runtimes from the past weeks and see if the job is gradually taking longer and longer.

I have read and implemented a lot of answers from StackOverflow and other internet resources but none of them fit my purpose. When using unix timestamps (since 1970, etc) I get columns that are all of the same hight and Y-axis ticks in years instead of hours from 1970 to now.

Another option was to just calculate the minutes or seconds. Then the difference become appearant, but instead of time elements in the Y axis and tooltips I get integers.

Can someone show me how to achieve my goal in a fiddle? The question looks common enough to me for any monitoring software.

-- EDIT --
Here is a Photoshop sample of what I am trying to achieve:
[image: Time taken of backups]
On the Y-axis: a time scale. In the tooltip: date, objectname and time taken.
-- END EDIT --

BTW, I have no chart type preference. The usual column charts just seem to fit the purpose.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi, [xrange series](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/x-range) looks fit to your goals, let me know what do you think about this type chart. You can check other [charts demo](https://www.highcharts.com/demo)

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. I don't see how the Gantt chart can help comparing the time taken by each occurrence. I have added a sample column chart. The problem is the timescale on the left and the time in the tooltip. In red the failed backup :(

Comment: Other answers on the internet lead to a time in the tooltip that is just the unix timstamp value (x1000). They probably worked in previous versions of HighCharts, but not in mine (9.3.2).